# Number of primitive steps in a for-loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am reading about algorithms' complexity. And I have a code for which I'm suppose to tell it's number of primitive operations.

```
sum_res = 0     #1
for num in num_list:  # 5 * n + 2
    sum_res += num   #  n * 1
mean = sum_res / len(num_list) # 3
```

I understand that line 1 is 1 operation. And line 3 is 1 operation but because it's been executing n times, it makes it n operations in total. And last line is 3 operations. But I don't understand why is the loop **5 * n + 2**

I would really appreciate if someone could break it down for me.

Comment: Who told you that the loop is `5*n + 2` operations? I need some source.

Comment: My instructor did. I don't have a source exactly. It's from his lectures.

Comment: The exact formula is hardly relevant. The key point is that it's O(n).

Comment: I understand it's O(n) but why is loop 5n+2. How do you calculate the number of primitive steps for a for-loop?

Comment: Maybe there's some info missing in your slides, or you have posted an incomplete question. Python (usually loops in all languages), run for as long as the condition to run the loop remains true (something like, O(untilConditionTrue)).

Comment: Also, the last line is just 1 operation, O(1). That's because, `len` is constant time, division is also constant time, and you have already found out `sum_res`. I maybe off, by what you mean as operations (maybe you mean that operations is the number of different tasks happening, or something like that), but in respect to what is taught in algorithms, it is O(1).

Comment: Yes by operation I mean, the number of tasks happening. So for last line, it needs to compute a division, which is one operation (and it needs len(num_list) before it can do this, which is another operation), and then write the result in a new variable. So that's 3 steps in total. But now I want to figure out why the number of steps/tasks happening in a loop are 5n+2

Comment: Looks like I missed the fact that you are talking about primitive basic operations. Need a primitive operations expert here...!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your instructor is getting those numbers from. If you want to see the primitive operations that the stack-based Python virtual machine executes for a piece of code you can use the [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) function.

From the docs:

> `dis.dis(x=None, *, file=None, depth=None)`
>
> Disassemble the `x` object. `x` can denote either a module, a class, a
>   method, a function, a generator, an asynchronous generator, a
>   coroutine, a code object, a string of source code or a byte sequence
>   of raw bytecode. For a module, it disassembles all functions. For a
>   class, it disassembles all methods (including class and static
>   methods). For a code object or sequence of raw bytecode, it prints one
>   line per bytecode instruction. It also recursively disassembles nested
>   code objects (the code of comprehensions, generator expressions and
>   nested functions, and the code used for building nested classes).
>   Strings are first compiled to code objects with the `compile()` built-in
>   function before being disassembled. If no object is provided, this
>   function disassembles the last traceback.

We can put your code into a string and pass it to `dis.dis` like this:

```
from dis import dis

src = '''\
sum_res = 0
for num in num_list:
    sum_res += num
mean = sum_res / len(num_list)
'''
dis(src)
```

**output**

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (sum_res)

  2           4 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 26)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (num_list)
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_NAME               2 (num)

  3          14 LOAD_NAME                0 (sum_res)
             16 LOAD_NAME                2 (num)
             18 INPLACE_ADD
             20 STORE_NAME               0 (sum_res)
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK

  4     >>   26 LOAD_NAME                0 (sum_res)
             28 LOAD_NAME                3 (len)
             30 LOAD_NAME                1 (num_list)
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             34 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             36 STORE_NAME               4 (mean)
             38 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Hopefully, you can roughly follow what's going on there, but please see the `dis` docs for the meanings of the various instructions.